# Multiplying multiple columns with the same single column in a Multi-index column Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have this data frame

```
col = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Cost'],
                                ['WK1', 'WK2', 'WK3', 'Cost']])
data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 4), columns=col)
data
```

and I want to multiply all the column in Jan with cost so i tried it like this

```
data[['Jan']] * data[['Cost']]
```

but it fills my values with Nan. Is there a way i can do this?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need remove `[]` for selecting `DataFrame` with [`mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html):

```
print (data['one'].mul(data['two']))
```

Or:

```
print (data['one'] * data['two'])
```

Also is possible use function [`xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html):

```
print (data.xs('one', axis=1, level=0) * data.xs('two', axis=1, level=0))
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can guess, you have trouble accessing columns using multi level index. Is this what you are trying to do?

```
data[('one','a')] * data[('two','b')]
Out[1065]: 
0    0.528834
1   -0.287322
2   -0.255244
3    0.871213
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys I made a for cycle to answer my question

```
for col in data['Jan']:
 data[('Jan', col)] = data[('Jan',col)] * data[('Cost','Cost')]
```

Hope someone can give me a feedback in what i can improve